# pandas groupby to new columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table

| Group | Value | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | AAAA |
| 1 | 1.2 | BBBB |
| 2 | 1.4 | CCCC |
| 2 | 1.6 | DDDD |
| 3 | 0.4 | EEEE |
| 3 | 0.3 | FFFF |

I'd like to transform the table to the following by grouping by the group ID:

| Group | Value_1 | Name_1 | Value_2 | Name_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | AAAA | 1.2 | BBBB |
| 2 | 1.4 | CCCC | 1.6 | DDDDD |
| 3 | 0.4 | EEEE | 0.3 | FFFF |

For now a solution, assuming there are only two rows per group is fine, but if possible I'd like to see a solution with more than two rows.

Comment: Check out the "group by" function in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#grouping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a counter for each group and then unstack:

```
df_wide = (df.assign(count=(df.groupby("Group").cumcount() + 1).astype(str))
             .set_index(["Group", "count"])
             .unstack("count")
             .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df_wide.columns = df_wide.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)

df_wide

      Name_1  Value_1 Name_2  Value_2
Group                                
1       AAAA      1.1   BBBB      1.2
2       CCCC      1.4   DDDD      1.6
3       EEEE      0.4   FFFF      0.3
```